# C++ Pointers in C# MVVM

Tags: c#, c++, mvvm, clr

Currently, I am working on a project in C# which use C++ libraries. To use the C++ libraries they are wrapped in CLR. Communication between the C++ and C# are in both ways.

I have the following problem. At a point the C++ calls some functions in CLR which will raise events with objects that have C++ raw pointers.

For example:

C++ object

```
class CObject {
  private:
     char* ptr;
}
```

CLR object

```
ref class CLRObject {
    public: CLRObject(CObject* p) : m_native(p) {}
    private: CObject* m_native;
}
```

C# object

```
class CSHObject : CLRObject {
}
```

Now because CSHObject is send as an argument to the event to multiple handlers they will all get a reference to the same object. So when one of the event handlers will modify the object which is pass by the event, the other listeners of the event will get the modified object.

For example:

C++ creates the object:

```
void updateListeners() {
    updateListener(new CObject());
}
```

CLR overwrites the updateListener:

```
void updateListener(CObject* obj) {
     m_wrapper->updateListener(gcnew CLRObject(obj))
}
```

C# will raise the event:

```
public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> MyEvent;
void updateListener(CLRObject obj) {
    MyEvent?.Invoke(this, new MyEventArgs(new CSHObject(obj)));
}
```

Now my question, how we should handle these events? from the point of MVVM view. Because the CLRObject is the Model in this case, but the same model is shared between multiple view models. Which I think is not the correct way of the MVVM.

So:

1. should all the event listeners create their own Models and copy the required information from the CLRObject?
2. each event listener create a deep copy of the object?
3. the current implementation is the correct way and I should not change.

Obs:

1. I don't have good knowledge in C#, CLR.
2. All the example code is made up, because the real code is too long and contains a lot of other things.

Comment: Does the event arguments contain anything which sends information back to C++? E.g. `bool CancelEvent`, or anything with methods which can be called which have effects back in C++-land?

Comment: @Ben The events don't contain anything which sends information back to C++. But there are other methods which have effects in C++. For example methods to change a data member of a C++ object.